# Remove blue background in select dropdown IE9

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, dropdown

I am using IE9 and can't remove the blue background when a select dropdown is focused. When an item is selected from any of the drop downs the element is overlaid with a blue box. It doesn’t occur on Chrome or Firefox.

This code removes it for IE10 and Edge

```
select::-ms-value {
    background: none; /* remove blue background on ie10/ie11 when selected*/
    color:#5a5a5a;

}
```

Comment: Have you tried background: none!important?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895476/how-to-style-a-select-dropdown-with-css-only-without-javascript

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem and I resolved it using this:

```
select:focus::-ms-value {
      background-color: white; 
      color:#000;
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Working in IE10 but not IE9